# How to delete dynamically-created controls in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have this program that creates control(textboxes, progressbars, labels, timers) dynamically. Now I created a button that when clicked, will erase the created controls on the form. What's the code to this?

Comment: I don't have any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the controls keep the references around. For example you can use a list as a global variable.

```
Dim MyControls as List(Of Control)
```

When you create the controls you add them to the form's control collection and also to the list

```
MyControls = New List(Of Control)
[...]
Me.Controls.Add(NewControl)
MyControls.Add(NewControl)
```

Do delete the controls you remove them from the form and dispose them (free ressources)

```
For each c as Control in MyControls
  Me.Controls.Remove(c)
  c.Dispose()
Next
```

You can do this because controls are reference types. That means the objects in both the `MyControls` list and the ones displayed on the form point to the same instance and you can therefore dispose them easily afterwards.

Comment: My code in creating controls is this:  `Private burstbox As New List(Of TextBox)` , adding control is this: `burstbox.Add(New TextBox)`. what will be my code for deleting the textboxes then?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jens said above

```
    For each tb as TextBox in burstbox
        burstbox.Remove(tb)
        tb.Dispose()
    Next
```